# Change just the string of an AttributedString (e.g. UIButton configuration attributedTitle)

Tags: ios, swift, attributedstring

Starting in iOS 15, Swift provides the AttributedString struct that embodies a string's text along with its style attributes. Question: given an existing AttributedString, and assuming (for the sake of simplicity) that the attributes consist of a single style run, how can you change *just the string part* of an AttributedString?

---

Here's a typical use case — a UIButton. Suppose I have a configuration-based button, with an attributed title:

```
let button = UIButton(configuration: .plain())
let font = UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 16)
button.configuration?.attributedTitle = AttributedString(
    "Hello", attributes: AttributeContainer.font(font!)
)
```

If I later come along and set the configuration's title to a different title, the attribute information is lost. For example:

```
button.configuration?.title = "Goodbye"
// Button title is no longer in Georgia font!
```

What I want to do here, evidently, is to replace the *text* of an attributed string title without disturbing its *attributes*. But Swift's AttributedString doesn't seem to provide a way to do that.

So, as I asked at the outset: What's the correct approach here?

Comment: Everything about UIButton.Configuration has caused me pain since it was introduced. Thank you for digging into one of the messes.

Comment: @RobNapier I'm in the process of converting all of our app's buttons into configuration-based buttons, so this is a learning curve that I've been steadily climbing. I'm now pretty nimble with them!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changing the text of an AttributedString is remarkably tricky. You have to replace the contents of the attributed string's character view — its `characters` property. To make things even harder, you cannot do this simply by assigning another string!

Using our button as an example, this won't compile:

```
button.configuration?.attributedTitle?.characters = "Goodbye" // error
```

Nor is it sufficient to derive the character view from a simple string. This doesn't compile either:

```
button.configuration?.attributedTitle?.characters = "Goodbye".characters // error
```

This is because the separate character view of a simple string no longer exists; you're still trying to assign a String into a character view, and we already know you can't do that.

Instead, you can make an AttributedString.CharacterView directly from your String and assign *that* into the target attributed string's `characters` property. Swift inferred typing is a big help here:

```
button.configuration?.attributedTitle?.characters = .init("Goodbye")
```

That replaces the button's title without disturbing the button's title's style attributes.

#### More about buttons

Replacing a button's title is such a useful thing to be able to do that I've made a little utility extension on UIButton that covers all the cases — a button that isn't configuration-based, a button that is configuration-based but has no attributed title, and a button that is configuration-based and has an attributed title:

```
extension UIButton {
    func replaceTitle(_ newTitle: String) {
        guard configuration != nil else {
            setTitle(newTitle, for: .normal)
            return
        }
        guard configuration?.attributedTitle != nil else {
            configuration?.title = newTitle
            return
        }
        configuration?.attributedTitle?.characters = .init(newTitle)
    }
}
```

#### Even more about buttons

It may be (and has been) asked, in the case of the configuration-based button, why use the `attributedTitle` at all? Why not set the font in the button configuration's `buttonConfig.titleTextAttributesTransformer`?

That answer is that that doesn't work for real-life fonts that need to respond dynamically to the user changing their text size preference. To see what I mean, try this example:

```
let button = UIButton(configuration: .plain())
let font = UIFontMetrics(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
    .scaledFont(for: UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 16)!)
button.configuration?.title = "Hello"
button.configuration?.titleTextAttributesTransformer = .init { container in
    container.merging(AttributeContainer.font(font))
}
```

You will see that, although the button title appears initially in the correct font, and although the font survives setting the button's configuration title, the *dynamism* of the font size has been lost. With a dynamically sized font, you *must* set the font as part of the attributed title.

This is, in fact, the use case that ultimately inspired my original question, and hence this answer.